# Why does my MBP say it was restarted "because of a problem"?

Tags: macbook-pro, restart

Since upgrading my MBP from Lion to Mountain Lion, every time I restart (planned restart, with nothing abnormal - I even close all applications before selecting Restart), my MacBook briefly shows the message "Your computer restarted because of a problem" when booting. Then, once I've logged in, I also see a dialog that says "Your computer was restarted because of a problem". As far as I know, there is no problem; everything seems to be working normally.

How can I begin to diagnose or get rid this? It's merely a cosmetic issue, I think, but it is annoying. I have read [this Apple support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3742), but that only seems to be relevant in the scenario where the Mac crashed because of a kernel panic. As far as I know, mine didn't.

Comment: Does your Console.app log tell you anything more about the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Resetting my NVRAM / PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379) appears to have resolved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same annoying issue on OSX Mavericks (10.9.2), and [resetting the NVRAM / PRAM as per Andrew Ferrier's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/75257/3245) didn't resolve it.

Instead, I opened a Terminal window and found a week old Kernel `.panic` file in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/`

I simply renamed it to `.panic.old` with the following command:

```
sudo mv Kernel_[rest_of_filename].panic Kernel_[rest_of_filename].panic.old
```

After a reboot I no longer get the annoying message!

Comment: Did not resolve it in my case…

Comment: Update: actually, it did help, but I had to move the new `.contents.panic` file as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Big Sur. NVRAM/PRAM reset didn't work, but resetting the SMC apparently did:

https://support.apple.com/en-euro/HT201295

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can receive this issue by holding down your power-button to restart it. Are you hitting the restart button in OS X, or are you just holding down the power button?